# How to convert 2nd order differential equation to first order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have an exam in about 2 hours and I just want to know the steps involved in converting $$\ddot{x}+2k\dot{x}+\omega^2_0x=0$$ into two first order differential equations.

I need to be able to draw its trajectories in a phase plane.

I'm thinking you re-write $$\ddot{x}=-2k\dot{x}-\omega^2_0x$$

Let $y=\dot{x}$ we have

$$\dot{y}=-2k{y}-\omega^2_0 x$$
$$\dot{x}= y $$

How do I write that as a matrix and compute the eigenvalues? Do I have to write this

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1 \\ -\omega^2_0 && -2k  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

or can I write this instead

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1 \\ -1 && -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to be able to compute the eigenvalues so I can draw a phase portrait. Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: First matrix is OK. This is only the second matrix if $w_0 = 1$ and $k = 1$. Look in your notes for finding the eigenvalues of a 2 by 2 matrix - you must have done several examples?

Comment: I know how to solve eigenvalues. My confusion lies in solving the first matrix. I got eigenvalues $$\lambda_{\pm}= -k\pm i\sqrt{\omega_0^2-k^2}$$ cause it's stated in the problem that $k^2<\omega_0^2 \implies $ underdamping. For some reason I think this doesn't look right, it seems messy or something.

Comment: never mind, I understand it now :) It's the roots to the characteristic polynomial for underdamping simple harmonic motion. Appreciate the help. Sometimes you just confuse yourself for no reason.

Comment: Writing out your problem is often enough.